# Why is a serializable inner class not serializable?

Tags: java, serialization, inner-classes

The following code:

```
public class TestInnerClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new TestInnerClass().serializeInnerClass();
    }

    private void serializeInnerClass() throws IOException {
        File file = new File("test");
        InnerClass inner = new InnerClass();
        new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)).writeObject(inner);
    }

    private class InnerClass implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    }

}
```

throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException: TestInnerClass
```

I guess the inner class has a `TestInnerClass.this` field that allows it private access to `TestInnerClass`'s fields and methods. Declaring the inner class static [solves it](http://www.coderanch.com/t/268954/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/inner-classes-serialization), but what if `InnerClass` needs this access? Is there a way to serialize a non-static inner class without the enclosing class, e.g. by making the reference to the outer class `transient`?

edit: for example, access to the outer class could be needed only before serialization. OK, the compiler cannot know that, but I thought that's why the `transient` keyword exists.

Comment: did you try to declare inner class static? `private static class InnerClass`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> what if InnerClass needs this access?

Then it needs the outer class instance, and it must be serialized along with the inner class.

> Is there a way to serialize a non-static inner class without the enclosing class, e.g. by making the reference to the outer class transient?

No. What would happen when you deserialize such a class and then try to call an instance method of the outer class? A `NullPointerException`?

Comment: In my situation, the inner class needs access before it is actually serialized (not after deserialization). It is afterwards only used as a superclass who does not know of the outer class.

Comment: @tb189: You can always break the non-static dependency by adding a field `transient TestInnerClass parentClass` to `InnerClass` and take care of it when deserializing.

Comment: That would indeed be a way to deal with it, and resembles a transient reference to the `TestInnerClass.this`.

Comment: @dma_k `outerClass`, you mean. outer != parent. Although you're right that it is the solution.

Comment: @Boann: In the example above `InnerClass` is inner class, `TestInnerClass` is outer class. If given inner class would be nested class, then the exception wouldn't be raised, as nested class has no implicit reference to it's container class. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class) concerning the terminology.

Comment: @dma_k Hmm? I know. Why are you telling me?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought that you asked for clarification. Yes, you're right, I meant `TestInnerClass outerClass`, but I cannot edit my comment.

Answer (score 2):

how about make TestInnerClass serializable?

```
public class TestInnerClass implements Serializable { }
```

Comment: That's possible, but not always desired, since that adds a lot of data to the serialized class.

Comment: @EJP: there are always solutions that could be more preferable (separating the parts of the inner class that need access and then forward it to a static serializable class, using a transient field TestInnerClass, maintainging another serializable object in the inner class). It would also imply declaring all fields in the outer class transient, which seems like a design flaw. It's not because the present situation doesn't work that the first alternative/hack should immediately be used.

Answer (score 2):

InnerClass cannot be serialised because to instantiate it (as required during deserialization) you need a reference to an instance of the outer class

Instances of inner classes cannot exist without an instance of the outer class.

i.e

```
OuterClass o = new OuterClass();
OuterClass.InnerClass o_i = o.new InnerClass();
```

If you use static inner class, it will be possible to serialise the static inner class. The instances of static inner classes can be created standalone.

i.e

```
OuterClass o = new OuterClass();
OuterClass.InnerClass i = new OuterClass.InnerClass();
```

Comment: Perhaps making a Github gist or a full reproducible example would be nice, don't you think?