# Java, Serialization, can you serialize a class within a class

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is a serializable inner class not serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144912/why-is-a-serializable-inner-class-not-serializable)

I have a class that does not implement `Serializable`. Inside of that class I have a data class which holds data for the whole program which implements `Serializable` and has a version ID.

My problem is that when I try to serialze a data object with in my main class I get a object write error from the main class and not the data class. The main class does not implement `Serializable`.

Can you serialize a class within a non-serializable class?

Example:

```
class main
{
   class data implements Serializable
   {  // data and functions }

   public void main(args)
   { data d = new data();
     // ofcourse I have the proper inits and checks for the output stream and such
     writeObject(data);  // Throws Class not Serializable error.}
}
```

Comment: If your `data` class is `static` I think it should be possible.

Comment: What is this `.writeObject()` method? `data` is no `ObjectOutputStream` here.

Comment: I know I am writing the code right, it is a more abstract question than did I write the code right. And yes artbristol I think it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As `data` is not `static` it implicitly has a reference to its outer class `main` which is not Serializable.

Try making the class `static`.

Comment: I am not new to java by no means but making the class static has what presumptions? Why does making it static work?

Comment: static means it doesn't have an implict reference to the outer class i.e. it removes a reference to a class which is not Serializable.  BTW I would make every nested classes `static` if you can.

Comment: @user1596244 one difference code-wise is that if you were to access your `data` class from outside `main`, you would need an instance of `main` in order to instantiate `data`, like in (ewww) `new main().new data()`. If `data` is static, you just have to `new main.data()` without having to have an instance of `main`.

Comment: A member of my very outer non-serial class is data d = new Data();. Making data class static,, does this mean that methods and functions within the outer class can or cannot still access this data d object. I figure it has no problem. (TYPO in OP, I have data d, outside of main)

Comment: Making `data` static would mean it cannot reference a `main` as this is not Serializable.

Comment: So with it static, it cannot access any fields or functions in its encapsulating/outer class. But fields and methods in the outer class can access fields and methods in the data class, right?  --- This is good, I only want data to hold data. Let me write to it, and read from it, it does not need to access and outer class functions or fields. Is this right?

Comment: The outer class can access anything in the inner class if it has a reference to an instance. The inner class can access anything on the outer class if it has a reference to it.  What `static` is there is no *implicit* reference to an instance of the outer class.

Comment: So if I do want my inner class to access the outer one, I need to make a method within the inner class to set a reference to a class, the reference pointing to the outer class?

Comment: You would have to make the reference `transient` so it is not serialized as it can't be and reset it when the class is deserialized.

Comment: Thank you Peter, this makes a whole lot of sense now!

Answer (score 3):

If you decompiled your main.class you would see that in the real code

```
public class main {

    class data implements Serializable {
        final main this$0;

        data() {
            this$0 = main.this;
        }
    }
}
```

`data` contains a reference to its outer class `main`. This so called synthetic field is added by javac. When ObjectOutputStream is trying to serizalize data it stumbles upon a reference to a non-serializable class and breaks. So to be serializable you should make `main` implement Serializable too, or make `data` static class then the reference to `main` will go