# Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object getactivity()

Tags: android, android-intent, serialization

so I am getting this in logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.resources.student_list.Student)
```

I know this means that my student class is not serializable, but it is, here is my student class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;


public class Student implements Comparable<Student>,  Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String firstName, lastName;
    private DSLL<Grade> gradeList; 

    public Student() {
        firstName = "";
        lastName = "";
        gradeList = new DSLL<Grade>();
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public DSLL<Grade> getGradeList() {
        return gradeList;
    }

    public void setGradeList(DSLL<Grade> gradeList) {
        this.gradeList = gradeList;
    }

    public int compareTo(Student arg0) {
        return this.lastName.compareTo(arg0.getLastName());
    }

}
```

and this is the code that is using the getIntent() method:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int pos,
                                long id) {

                            Student clickedStudent = studentList.get(pos);
                            int position = pos;
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ShowStudentActivity.class);
                            Log.e("CINTENT","CREATED!!!");
                            intent.putExtra("clickedStudent",clickedStudent);
                            intent.putExtra("newStudentList",newStudentList);
                            intent.putExtra("position",position);
                            Log.e("putExtra","Passed");
                            Log.e("Start activity","passed");
                            startActivity(intent);

                        } 

                    });
```

please help me figure out whats wrong with this.

here is the whole LogCat:

```
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815): java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.resources.student_list.Student)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1181)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1135)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:493)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1612)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:507)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:6111)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1613)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1422)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3191)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:848)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:878)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at com.example.student_lists.MainActivity$DummySectionFragment$2.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:477)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1058)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2514)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3168)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4447)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815): Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.resources.student_list.DSLL$DNode
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1364)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:979)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1074)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:979)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1074)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
04-17 16:12:28.890: E/AndroidRuntime(22815):    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1176)
```

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the entire Java stack trace associated with your exception. If you do not understand the stack trace, paste it here. Also, what is `DSLL` and what is `Grade`?

Comment: DSLL(DoubleSortedLinckedList) and Grade another class created by me, both of them are also serializable.

Comment: I posted the LogCar stack trace

Comment: Not directly related, but... in my case I was attempting to serialise an inner class defined inside a non-serializable outer class. I learnt that **non-static inner classes contain a reference to their outer class** (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144912/why-is-a-serializable-inner-class-not-serializable)).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61758963/how-to-ignore-fields-when-using-parcelize-annotation-in-kotlin.

Answer (score 397, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.resources.student_list.DSLL$DNode
```

Your `DSLL` class appears to have a `DNode` static inner class, and `DNode` is not `Serializable`.

Comment: @user2896762: In general, on Android, start from the bottom of the stack trace and work your way up to the last `Caused by` line. That's usually going to point to the specific problem. All the other stanzas of the stack trace represent wrapped exceptions around the "real" exception at the bottom of the trace.

Comment: Thanks!!!  @user2896762 & @CommonsWare  I read the Stack trace...Found One of the object in my class was Not Serialized. and Now It is working.
`Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:`

Comment: @CommonsWare How to use above code. Can you help me pls?

Comment: Each and every inner class in Model must be serialize .

Comment: You indicated the cause, but not the solution! I think Fransisco answer should be the accepted one.

Comment: I've got this same error in only android version 10 using androidX https://stackoverflow.com/q/62679149/7832102 @CommonsWare

Answer (score 99):

Your OneThread Class also should implement Serializable. All the ***sub classes*** and ***inner sub classes*** must **implements Serializable**.

this is worked for me...

Answer (score 35):

if your POJO contains any other model inside that should also implements Serializable

Answer (score 33):

If you can't make DNode serializable a good solution would be to add "transient" to the variable.

Example:

```
public static transient DNode dNode = null;
```

This will ignore the variable when using Intent.putExtra(...).

Comment: The `transient` keyword in Java is used to indicate that a field should not be serialized. Full answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/910522/1306012

Comment: This is the correct answer. Not only does the Class have to be Serializable, but some Attributes of the Class need to be declared TRANSIENT. Examples: DatabaseReference, Query, Constants and any others that MUST NOT BE SERIALIZED

Answer (score 9):

For me this was resolved by making the variable withing the class transient.

Code before:

```
public class UserLocation implements Serializable {
   public Location lastKnownLocation;
   public UserLocation() {}
}
```

code after

```
public class UserLocation implements Serializable {
    public transient Location lastKnownLocation;
    public UserLocation() {}
}
```

Comment: This cannot work for me. I cannot make it transient because I actually need the value of that variable somewhere else in my codebase.

Comment: This helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

The exception occurred due to the fact that any of the inner classes or other referenced classes didn't implement the serializable implementation. So make sure that all the referenced classes must implement the serializable implementation.

Comment: Correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

The problem occurs when your custom class has for property some other class e.g. "Bitmap". What I made is to change the property field from  "private Bitmap photo" to "private transient Bitmap photo". However the image is empty after I getIntent() in the receiver activity. Because of this I passed the custom class to the intent and also I've created a  byte array from the image and pass it separatly to the intent:

selectedItem is my custom object and getPlacePhoto is his method to get image. I've already set it before and now I just get it first than convert it and pass it separatly:

```
 Bitmap image = selectedItem.getPlacePhoto();
 image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
 byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
 Intent intent = new Intent(YourPresentActivity.this, 
 TheReceiverActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("selectedItem", selectedItem);                 
 intent.putExtra("image", byteArray);
 startActivity(intent);
```

`

Then in the receiver activity I get my object and the image as byte array, decode the image and set it to my object as photo property.

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 selectedItem = (ListItem) intent.getSerializableExtra("selectedItem");
 byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
 Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, 
 byteArray.length);
 selectedItem.setPhoto(image);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Need to change all arraylist to Serializable wif in bean class :**

```
public static class PremiumListBean  implements Serializable {
    private List<AddOnValueBean> AddOnValue;

    public List<AddOnValueBean> getAddOnValue() {
        return AddOnValue;
     }

    public void setAddOnValue(List<AddOnValueBean> AddOnValue) {
        this.AddOnValue = AddOnValue;
    }


    public static class AddOnValueBean  implements Serializable{

        @SerializedName("Premium")
        private String Premium;

        public String getPremium() {
            return Premium;
        }

        public void setPremium(String Premium) {
            this.Premium = Premium;
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced Same issue, the issues was there are some inner classes with the static keyword.After removing the static keyword it started working and also the inner class should implements to Serializable

### Issue scenario

```
class A implements Serializable{ 
  class static B{
  } 
}
```

### Resolved By

```
class A implements Serializable{ 
      class B implements Serializable{
      } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also phase these error and i am little bit change in **modelClass which are implemented Serializable interface** like:

At that Model class also implement **Parcelable interface** with **writeToParcel()** override method

Then just got error to *"create creator"* so **CREATOR** is write and also create with *modelclass contructor with arguments & without arguments*..

```
       @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeString(id);
            dest.writeString(name);
        }

        protected ArtistTrackClass(Parcel in) {
            id = in.readString();
            name = in.readString();
        }

       public ArtistTrackClass() {

        }

    public static final Creator<ArtistTrackClass> CREATOR = new Creator<ArtistTrackClass>() {
        @Override
        public ArtistTrackClass createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ArtistTrackClass(in);
        }

        @Override
        public ArtistTrackClass[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ArtistTrackClass[size];
        }
    };
```

Here,

**ArtistTrackClass -> ModelClass**

Constructor with Parcel arguments *"read our attributes"* and writeToParcel() is *"write our attributes"*

Answer (score 0):

the Grade class must also implement Serializable

```
public class Grade implements Serializable {
.....your content....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to implement `MainActivity` as `Serializable` too. Cause I needed to start a service from my `MainActivity` :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Serializable {
    ...
    musicCover = new MusicCover(); // A Serializable Object
    ...
    sIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MusicPlayerService.class);
    sIntent.setAction(MusicPlayerService.ACTION_INITIALIZE_COVER);
    sIntent.putExtra(MusicPlayerService.EXTRA_COVER, musicCover);
    startService(sIntent);
}
```