# Searchable spinner crashes my app on multitasking

Tags: android, android-studio, crash, spinner, libraries

I am working with the library [Searchable Spinner](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3272), but if I press the android home button or multitasking button when I have open the spinner, the app crashes and print on screen: "Unfortunately, Appname has stoppeed."

My fragmentactivity:

```
public class buscadorFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {


public Button BotonRecargar;
public IndeterminateRoadRunner UCargando;
public TextView TextoPrueba;
public TextView TextoError;


private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public SearchableSpinner SpCateg;
public SearchableSpinner SpUbic;

String[] CategoriasArray = {"Categorias"};
String[] UbicacionesArray ={"Ubicaciones"};

ArrayAdapter<String> CatspinnerAdapter;
ArrayAdapter<String> UbicspinnerAdapter;



public buscadorFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_buscador, container, false);
CatspinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, CategoriasArray);
    CatspinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    SpCateg.setAdapter(CatspinnerAdapter);
    CatspinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    UbicspinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, UbicacionesArray);
        UbicspinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    SpUbic.setAdapter(UbicspinnerAdapter);
    UbicspinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



    SpCateg.setTitle("Categoría");
    SpCateg.setPositiveButton("Cancelar");

    SpUbic.setTitle("Ubicación");
    SpUbic.setPositiveButton("Cancelar");

    return view;    
}
```

My fragment layout:

only add

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/Category_Spinner" />

        <com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/Ubication_Spinner" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

There is the logcat:

```
08-31 20:09:21.656 18172-18172/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.kreativer.upy, PID: 18172
                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner)
                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1323)
                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1271)
                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:618)
                                                   at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1692)
                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:643)
                                                   at android.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:133)
                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1140)
                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:373)
                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1292)
                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1211)
                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:618)
                                                   at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1692)
                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:643)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:2643)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3252)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5426)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: android.widget.ArrayAdapter
                                                   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1366)
                                                   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1673)
                                                   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1519)
                                                   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
                                                   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:981)
                                                   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
                                                   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1076)
                                                   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1406)
                                                   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1673)
                                                   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1519)
                                                   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1318)
                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1271) 
                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:618) 
                                                   at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1692) 
                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:643) 
                                                   at android.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:133) 
                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1140) 
                                                   at android.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:373) 
                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1292) 
                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1211) 
                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:618) 
                                                   at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1692) 
                                                   at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:643) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:2643) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3252) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5426) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Crashes only when the spinner is opened, otherwise the app keep running.
I am newbie and want to learn, so thanks in advance.

Comment: See `Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: android.widget.ArrayAdapter` this main reason cause your app crashed. 
Can you provide adapter code? It will help us to solve problem.
[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142893/parcelable-encountered-ioexception-writing-serializable-object-getactivity) may helps you.

Comment: @pRaNaY ... the arrayAdapter class? from the librarie?, because on my fragment activity I have declarated the ArrayAdapter before OnCreateView and instantiated on OnCreateView...

Comment: can you tell me where can i find the Adapter code???

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is an issue with the library as other users reported the same issue on Github. 
For resolving the issue, you can dismiss the searchableListDialog in onPause() method.

So write the following code in `SearchableListDialog.java`

```
@Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Also here is the linked issue:
https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner/issues/21

Answer (score 0):

Add this library in app's gradle file, inside dependencies:

implementation 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'