# AndroidX : Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object only in Android version 10 devices

Tags: java, android, android-studio, androidx, android-10.0

I got `Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object` and it caused by `java.io.NotSerializableException: androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` error only in Android Version 10 devices.

I've searched many results for getting solutions to this problem but every solution I got, was telling to define `implement serializable` in both *inner class* and *sub inner class*  and I've done it, still, I got this error only in Android version 10 devices.

If I will use `transient` this keyword to define View or object then this error will fix but this same error comes with another view, adapter, and class.

**Logcat**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.android.ui.fragment.CustomViewFragment)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1850)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1797)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:945)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1584)
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1253)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1014)
        at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:11155)
        at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.startAppLockService(IActivityTaskManager.java:8468)
        at android.app.Activity.startAppLockService(Activity.java:8950)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8022)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3512)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2175)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7860)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
     Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1240)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1604)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1565)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1488)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1234)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1604)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1565)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1488)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1234)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:354)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1845)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1797) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:945) 
        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1584) 
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1253) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1014) 
        at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:11155) 
        at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.startAppLockService(IActivityTaskManager.java:8468) 
        at android.app.Activity.startAppLockService(Activity.java:8950) 
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8022) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3512) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2175) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7860) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

**Activity.java**

```
   public class BaseFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Serializable, View.OnClickListener {
    
        private static final String TAG = "BaseFragmentActivity";
        private Toolbar mToolbar;
        private ImageView tBtnSave, tBtnBack;
        private TextView tTxtTitle;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_base_fragment);
    
            mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            tBtnSave = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_btn_save);
            tBtnBack = findViewById(R.id.toolbarBtnBack);
            tTxtTitle = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        }

        ...
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            buildConfigField "Boolean", "DEBUG_MODE", "true"
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'

    //External Animation Library
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

**Edit and Fixed.**

```
public class BaseFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Serializable, View.OnClickListener {
    
        // By using `transient` keyword to define view or class to say it's not serialized view or class.

        private static final String TAG = "BaseFragmentActivity";
        private transient Toolbar mToolbar;
        private transient AppCompatImageView tBtnSave, tBtnBack;
        private transient AppCompatTextView tTxtTitle;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_base_fragment);
    
            mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            tBtnSave = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_btn_save);
            tBtnBack = findViewById(R.id.toolbarBtnBack);
            tTxtTitle = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        }

        ...
}
```

Comment: `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` does not implement `Serializable` interface. Looks like you are trying to serialize Toolbar.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu No sir, I haven't implement serializable anywhere except POJO class. Think If I have made Toolbar serialize than how it works completely in other devices below version 10.

Comment: Do you hold a reference to the `Toolbar` view on class-level?

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu No, please check it out my edited question for more clarification.

Comment: Please post your `CustomViewFragment`. And one more question: have you tried to implement saving fragment or activity state?

Comment: Does this issue happen when trying to start an activity?

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu My MainMctivity.java opens with no error but when I trying to open another activity I got this error.

Comment: Please, post the full code of a class that starts a new activity. I suppose it happens in a `CustomViewFragment`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217065/discussion-between-prince-and-jenea-vranceanu).

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu The has posted at `CustomRatioFragment : `  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-XQghicijG6fxxWZnD2sihZrXAYK1jxl/view?usp=sharing `BaseFragmentActivity :` https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zg1dH9mKzrWwyPMTF_nt0LF9d5dNm8sv/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

Looks like somewhere in your code, you are trying to write a whole `Fragment` (looks like it is `CustomViewFragment`) to parcel:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.android.ui.fragment.CustomViewFragment)
```

To be serializable your class and all its members have to implement `Serializable`. Because `Fragment`'s context is `Activity` (that is probably a subclass of `BaseFragmentActivity`) it also goes through the process of serialization. But neither `Fragment` nor `Activity` implements `Serializable` interface.

Comment: You are right that you've said: I have to make "serializable class and all its members have to implement Serializable" So I have defined `transient` keyword with all mandatory views, objects, and classes. Thanks for helping me, I'll never forget you.

Comment: Just a bit of minor advice: do not serialize Activities and Fragments (and basically anything that is related to `android.content.Context`).

Comment: But, what should I do if I pass object through bundle from activity to fragment putSerializable(key,object) there we need to make sure our fragmnet serializable and can you please explain Why we should not to implement serializable in fragments and  activities?

Comment: Activity is responsible for the connection between your UI, resources and business logic. "An activity provides the window in which the app draws its UI." - [source](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/intro-activities#tcoa). Fragment was created to help make Activity smaller.

Comment: When you pass data between fragments or activities you pass **pure data**. For example, you pass only user ID instead of the whole user profile using a bundle. On the receivers end you extract ID and load user profile. When you pass large amounts of data you risk getting `TransactionTooLargeException` - when amount of data passed is more than ± 1Mb.

Comment: @Prince, to put it simply: pass only what you need. You do not need a whole fragment, you need only something that it holds.

Comment: It seems informative for every Developer. Thanks brother for your time that I have taken for help.

Answer (score 2):

**Here Is Your Solution :**

transient is a variables modifier used in serialization. At the time of serialization, if we don't want to save value of a particular variable in a file, then we use transient keyword. When JVM comes across transient keyword, it ignores original value of the variable and save default value of that variable data type.

So, it uses quite rare in order to say to your compiler that this variable is not a part of serializable mathod.