# How to serialize a Class with an Interface instance attribute? Got NotSerializableException

Tags: java, android, serialization, interface

I have a class:

```
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

    public MyInterface myInterface;

    public String name;
    public int    value;

    public MyEntity(String name, int value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

And an Interface:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    void customFunction(int value);
}
```

The point of this structure would be to fulfill the purpose of **each and every instance of MyClass could have different implementation of customFunction(value).**

So just like:

```
MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity("My entity", 100);
    myEntity.myInterface = new MyInterface() {
        @Override
        public void customFunction(int value) {
            //This is my custom function.
            //This can be different for every instance of MyEntity class
        }
    };
```

However If I would like to serialize an instance of MyClass, I get **NotSerializableException**.

> java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   com.adamvarhegyi.duelsofcodrer.controller.MainActivity$1 at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1344)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:959)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:360)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1054)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1384)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
>   at
>   com.adamvarhegyi.duelsofcodrer.controller.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:62)
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

So my question is how could I achieve this? How could I serialize class instances with Interface instance attributes?

**Update:**

This is the full code to make it clearer:

(I have made inner classes from `MyEntity` and `MyInterface` to make it more simplified.)

```
package com.adamvarhegyi.duelsofcodrer.controller;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.adamvarhegyi.duelsofcodrer.R;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public interface MyInterface extends Serializable {
    void customFunction(int value);
}

public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

    public MyInterface myInterface;

    public String name;
    public int    value;

    public MyEntity(String name, int value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity("My entity", 100);

    myEntity.myInterface = new MyInterface() {
        @Override
        public void customFunction(int value) {
            //This is my custom function.
            //This can be different for every instance of MyEntity class
        }
    };


    //Trying to serialize
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("myfile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(myEntity);
        oos.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Have you managed to get it right?

Comment: @RafaelCardoso No, I still got the exception with your advise as well. Can you try this method whether is it work?

Comment: @RafaelCardoso I have updated the question with the full code.

Comment: Adam, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144912/why-is-a-serializable-inner-class-not-serializable . There is a problem in serializing inner classes. Try moving them to separate files and get back with the results ;)

Comment: @RafaelCardoso Well the classes were in separate package, I just moved them to the activity to post the code in whole. So the error still on. Sadly.

Comment: I have your exact code running ok here. I just cant seem why you have a problem. Are you using other data structures in your interface?

Comment: @RafaelCardoso I have the same code as above, try it and look the log for that exception it must be there. Drives me insane. Gona add bounty in 2 days.

Comment: I have found the problem. I will not get this bounty reward but I hope I could be able to help anyways! *:)* Check my edited post below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you define your class as a `public class MyEntity implements Serializable` you are basically defining that all atributes of `MyEntity` should be serializable. However, `MyInterface` is not, thus, the attribute `public MyInterface myInterface` cannot be serialized, and you get the `NotSerializableException` .

To fix that, your interface should be an instace of `Serializable`, so it should extend it.

```
public interface MyInterface extends Serializable 
{
    void customFunction(int value);
}
```

That way, `MyEntity` will have all attributes serializable, and no errors will be thrown. It is important to notice that all basic data types such as `int`, `float` etc can be serialized, as well as `Strings`.

#### EDIT

After much thinking and reading and re-reading the code, I've found your problem. When you do the following :

```
myEntity.myInterface = new MyInterface() {
    @Override
    public void customFunction(int value) {
        //This is my custom function.
        //This can be different for every instance of MyEntity class
    }
};
```

you are actually creating a brand-new ***nameless*** inner class which implements `MyInterface`. However, as this is an inner class, it makes reference to its parent class which is `Activity`. Activity is ***not*** serializable, so that is why it throws `NotSerializableException`.

How to fix that?

It will not be possible for you to create custom classes to-go *which are Serializable*. However, there is one way out.

You can either create a new Class (e.g. named `CustomInterfaceImplementation` ) in a separate file, and make instances of it, or make an inner class of your `Activity` which is `static` (note that this Activity will not be created inside your `onCreate()` method, because that wouldn't make any sense. It should be created outside any method's scope and inside the `Activity` scope).

So, for instance, you could have something like:

```
CustomInterfaceImplementation customImpl = new CustomInterfaceImplementation();
myEntity.myInterface = customImpl;
```

The above code would work, being `CustomInterfaceImplementation` either a **static** class within your `MainActivity` or a separate public java class.

*But what if I want to make on-the-go classes that varies from obj to obj?*

As I said, it will be dificult to make completely new classes that are `Serializable`. *HOWEVER*, you could *extract* all common code between all possible implementations, and just pass variables that could, well, vary. That way, you would maintain the `Serializable` characteristic, and may be able to achieve your goal.

Comment: If I try to simply write " implements Serializable" to my Interface just like to my class I got error message. "No implements clause allowed for interface" How do I make an interface serializable?

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi Im sorry, it should be `extends` instead of `implements` as an interface inherits from other

Comment: I still got the exception, could you try this method please to check whether is it really work?

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi could you post your project structure? Like, how your files as disposed?

Comment: Well I got these 2 classes in the package named "com.adamvarhegyi.myprojectname.junk" Nothing complicated. And I got an Activity to test the functionality.

Comment: Yes it is working. Thank you for your effort Rafael.

Answer (score 0):

Either make MyInterface Serializable, or add transient to myInterface like so:

```
    public class MyEntity implements Serializable {
        public transient MyInterface myInterface;
        // ...
    }
```

Making myInterface transient marks the variable to not be serialized.

Comment: I would like it to be serialized.

Comment: In that case, you would write... public interface MyInterface extends Serializable